# Whatsapp webhooks not receiving messages and nothing in the database

Tags: laravel, whatsapp-cloud-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzMtk.jpg)I am learning web programming. I am working on adding whatsapp webhook to my web app.
My understanding:
In my web app, i implemented sending a whatsapp message template programmatically. When a client replies, i want to be able to receive and reply to the client. I followed the tutorial on https://business.whatsapp.com/blog/how-to-use-webhooks-from-whatsapp-business-api in combination with the tutorial in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/set-up-webhooks#sample-app-endpoints.

My endpoint has be verifyed usefully. But when i send test message, i do not receive any message in my database. I was expecting the when i send test message/when client sends whatsapp message, which show successful, i should receive it in database.

whatsappcontroller.php

```
public function handleWebhook(Request $request)
    {
        $body = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        if ($body['field'] !== 'messages') {
            // not from the messages webhook so don't process
            return response()->json([], 400);
        }

        foreach ($body['value']['messages'] as $message) {
            $review = new Whatsapp();
            $review->phonenumber = $message['from'];
            $review->review = $message['text']['body'];
            $review->save();
        }
```

Route.php

```
Route::post('/webhooks', [whatsappController::class, 'handleWebhook']);
```

What am I not doing good or what do i need to understand about webhook. Because i am expecting that when messages are saved in database, then i can now use a get request url to get all the messages in my web page. Or is this not possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih2tt.jpg)

Comment: I noticed that the [notification payload](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/webhooks/components#notification-payload-object) doesn't appear to be correctly traversed in your code snippet. Are you getting the 400 error in your error log?

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule, NO

Comment: how are you sending a test message?

Comment: @kris gjika I have added picture how facebook asked to send test message. It is contained in the documentation